# Does the outcome of the first case change based on your decisions?

Tags: murder-by-numbers

In the first case of *Murder by Numbers*, there are three suspects, two of which are likely.

In my first and only playthrough, in the first case I named

> the stalker fan

as the murderer. Unfortunately, that person was actually innocent, which resulted in a specific event that gets referenced throughout the latter three cases, ie.

> the real killer, Tully, being murdered in a way that's staged like a suicide.

However, it seems like the game would've allowed me to accuse the real killer instead - which is surprising, since cases 2 and 3 seemed linear.

So - does the story really branches out based on the first case's outcome, or was I predestined to pick the wrong suspect?